# Typing two quote characters in a LaTeX document?

Tags: latex, tex-mode

I'm working with a LaTeX document.  I want to type `""` since I need this for `german.sty` in LaTeX.  Starting some time ago, Emacs thinks this is not a good idea.  I do not agree.

Right now I have to write `" SPC "` and then manually remove the blank space in between the quotation marks.

**How can I type two quotation marks in a row?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you are in tex-mode, and `"` is bound to `tex-insert-quote`.

If you never want that behavior, rebind the key to `self-insert-command`:

```
(define-key tex-mode-map "\"" #'self-insert-command)
```

If you want the default tex behavior but occasionally want to insert a pair of quotes, use a prefix arg: `C-2 "`.

Alternatively it seems like you can type `""""` to get `""`.

Answer (score 6):

You can type `C-q "` for the second quote to do a "quoted insert". This should override whatever behavior is preventing the insertion of two quotes.

`C-q` is commonly used for inserting literal characters, such as `C-q C-l` for a `^L` control character.